# How to bind textboxes to datagridview by using textbox array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, datagridview, textbox

I have three buttons which loads different tables into datagridview. Each table has different amount of textboxes. I know, that one of the ways to *connect* textboxes and dgv is

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count == 5)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    //textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    //richTextBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    //richTextBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                }
                if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count == 6)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    //textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    //textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    //richTextBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    //richTextBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
}
```

But its kinda long code and i want to try to make it clearer.
I want to use array of textboxes (if its even possible?), I tried this:

```
                int i = 1;
                TextBox[] textboxes = new TextBox[i];
                textboxes[0] = textBox1; textboxes[1] = textBox2;
                textboxes[2] = textBox2; textboxes[3] = textBox3;
                for (int j = 1; i < textboxes.Length; i++)
                {
                    //i dont know how to jump to the next cell of current row in the dtg
                }
```

Are there any other options besides textbox arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand the question right and you're looking for manual binding of `Textbox`es to `DataGridView`. Note, that there's also binding built into the Windows Forms.

Prerequsities in the following example:

- `DataGridView` named `dg`
- Each column has `Name` set
- Texboxes have their `Name` set to string "tb" and the column name (i.e. "tbID")
- `DataGridView.SelectionMode` is set to `FullRowSelect`
- button to load sample dataset into the `DataGridView` is not shown in the picture

[image]

C#:

```
// Sample data set
private void BtnLoadDg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable tb = new DataTable();
    tb.Columns.Add("ID");
    tb.Columns.Add("Model");
    tb.Columns.Add("Brand");
    tb.Columns.Add("Description");
    tb.Rows.Add(
    {
        1,
        "T87",
        "Tatra",
        "A classic streamlined car."
    });
    tb.Rows.Add(
    {
        2,
        "L&K A",
        "Laurin&Klement",
        "First L&K car from 1905."
    });
    this.dg.DataSource = tb;
}

private void dg_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dg.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dg.Columns)
        {
            Control[] tbs = Panel1.Controls.Find("tb" + col.Name, false);
            if (!Information.IsNothing(tbs) && tbs.Count > 0)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)tbs[0];
                DataGridViewCell cell = this.dg.Rows(this.dg.SelectedRows(0).Index).Cells(col.Index);
                tb.Text = cell.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.tbID.text = "";
        this.tbModel.text = "";
        this.tbBrand.text = "";
        this.tbDescription.text = "";
    }
}
```

VB.NET:

```or-tag-here
    ' Sample data set
    Private Sub BtnLoadDg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLoadDg.Click
        Dim tb As New DataTable
        tb.Columns.Add("ID")
        tb.Columns.Add("Model")
        tb.Columns.Add("Brand")
        tb.Columns.Add("Description")
        tb.Rows.Add({1, "T87", "Tatra", "A classic streamlined car."})
        tb.Rows.Add({2, "L&K A", "Laurin&Klement", "First L&K car from 1905."})
        Me.dg.DataSource = tb
    End Sub

    Private Sub dg_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dg.SelectionChanged
        If Me.dg.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dg.Columns
                Dim tbs() As Control = Panel1.Controls.Find("tb" & col.Name, False)
                If Not IsNothing(tbs) AndAlso tbs.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(tbs(0), TextBox)
                    Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = Me.dg.Rows(Me.dg.SelectedRows(0).Index).Cells(col.Index)
                    tb.Text = cell.Value
                End If
            Next
        Else
            Me.tbID.text = ""
            Me.tbModel.text = ""
            Me.tbBrand.text = ""
            Me.tbDescription.text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```